# Compute dimension of space of modular forms by counting Galois representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, galois-representations

It is known that we can compute the dimension of the space $S_{k}^{\mathrm{new}}(N, \chi)$ of new forms of weight $k\geq 2$ and level $N$ and Nebentypus $\chi$ via Riemann-Roch theorem or using Modular symbols (see [this](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/%7Egerg/papers/downloads/DSCFN.pdf) and [this](https://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/modular_symbols.html#ch-modsym). Note that the first reference only provides formulas for trivial Nebentypus). For $k = 1$, it seems that there's no general formula is known (see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61263/modular-forms-of-weight-one) for example). When $N=p$ is a prime and $\chi$ is a Legendre symbol modulo $p$, then one can compute the dimension by counting 2-dimensional Artin representations of conductor $p$ and determinant $\chi$ (see [this](https://spectrum.library.concordia.ca/36019/) well-written thesis), which gives a formula in terms of class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$ and number of certain quartic and quintic fields. This approach is based on Deligne-Serre's result

Here's a question: can we recover dimension formula for $S_{k}^{\mathrm{new}}(N)$ for $k\geq 2$ by counting number of Galois representations, as in the case $k = 1$? We can attach $\ell$-adic Galois representations to modular forms of weight $k \geq 2$ (using etale cohomology of modular curves), and if we assume that all the $\ell$-adic representations are arose in such way, then it may possible to compute (count) the dimension by counting $\ell$-adic representations instead. I think that is approach won't be easy, at least it seems impossible to directly generalize approach for $S_{1}^{\mathrm{new}}(p, \chi_{p})$ mentioned above.

Comment: I don't think so---this is the magic of modularity.  When $k=2$, this amounts to asking for a count of d-dim GL(2) type abelian varieties of conductor $N^d$.  What is the point of trying to count Galois representations directly?

Comment: I'd strongly second @Kimball's comment: we seem to have great difficulties understanding the class of Galois representations directly, and thus arises the amazing utility of conjectural-or-proven "modularity".

Comment: @Kimball The reason I thought about this approach is because of weight 1 case (the thesis I mentioned above), which actually counts number of artin representations with prescribed conductor and determinant, which seems very hard anyway. Is it possible to count the abelian varieties that you mentioned and recover dimension formula in that way?

Comment: @paulgarrett I agree with you. As I mentioned above, initial motivation was to apply approach that used in weight 1 case, which have very different nature from weight >= 2 cases.